# How can I render components conditionally in Next.js

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm building a Next.js project, and I wanted the Navbar to be on all pages except the "/dashboard" page.

All the solutions I saw stated to use:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

but I guess that has been deprecated because the Next.js docs says to use

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
```

which would require that I include `"use client"`.

When I try to run that, I get this error:

```
Failed to compile

./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@vercel/og/index.node.js:18677:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/image-response.js
./node_modules/next/server.js
../node_modules/@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/dist/server/index.js
./src/components/Navigation.tsx
./src/app/layout.tsx
```

Here's what my code looks like so far

```
"use client";

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Rubik } from "next/font/google";
import styles from "./layout.module.css";
import Navigation from "@/components/Navigation";
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar";

const rubik = Rubik({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
  weight: ["300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"],
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Finnect",
  description: "Seamless transactions for everyone",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const pathName = usePathname();

  return (
    <html lang="en" className={rubik.className}>
      <body className={styles.container}>
        <Navigation />
        <nav>{pathName !== "/dashboard" && <Navigation />}</nav>
        <main>
          <Sidebar>{children}</Sidebar>
          {children}
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: The error "Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'" occurs in Next.js when you try to import the fs module in a client-side component. The fs module is a Node.js module that provides access to the file system. It is not available in the browser, so you cannot use it in client-side code.

Comment: To fix this error, you need to move the code that imports the fs module to a server-side component. Server-side components are executed on the server before the page is rendered to the browser. This means that they have access to the file system and can use the fs module.